# How to set file source via Parameter in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have multiple packages for each location site and each site contains 5 other sub sites for which data has to be populated every month. Hence I have approx 20 excel files as a source data for which the excel file acts as a source and I need to create an excel destination. Because of so many excel file as a source I have multiple Excel connection Managers (Source + Destination) across my various packages.

The source file name and the location will change everytime and so I was thinking to automate the file path via parameter. I follow the steps mentioned in the article:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlgardner/2015/06/18/ssis-tip-using-a-file-path-parameter-for-multiple-flat-files/

I followed every step but I got the error when I open the excel file (source). Below is the error snapshot:

[image]

Can someone guide me what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using an expression on the excel connection manager "ConnectionString" 
 property.  When that property is changed to just a file path that isn't a valid connection string for that type of connection.

With excel file connections it's a little different and you'll want to use the ExcelFilePath property, which in turn is used by the connection manager when building out the connection string.

[image]

With Flat File Connections, yes you would use the ConnectionString property, Excel Connections, slightly different, use the ExcelFilePath property.

Comment: How to fetch the Excel File Path from a variable ? which is in the Foreach Loop Container