# How to pass the excel connection string dynamically in the foreach loop container for Excel Source?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

How to pass the excel connection string dynamically in the foreach loop container for Excel Source?

In the Foreach Loop Container, I have the variable set to the Expressions / Directory.

In the Excel Source, I have mapped the Excel Connection String with the same variable mentioned in the Foreach loop Container.

However, I am getting an error

> This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

[image]

Comment: You want to use the ExcelFilePath property not ConnectionString when wanting to dynamically change the Excel Connection via an expression:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962691/how-to-set-file-source-via-parameter-in-ssis/52970144#52970144

Comment: Thank you Tim, In my case that folder path which you see it on the answer screen shot is picked from  a variable.  Folder path is set in a variable

Comment: How to fetch the Excel File Path from a variable ? which is in the Foreach Loop Container

Comment: I think I understand. Don't use the same variable you are using for the Foreach Loop.  I assume your User::InboundFilePath is where all the excel files are located you want to process.  Create a second variable and then in the foreach loop make sure "Retrieve file name" is set to Fully Qualified, under Variable Mappings select that second variable you created with index 0. Now use that new variable on the ExcelFilePath property via an expression. The foreach loop works through each of the files it assigns the full path and name to the new variable, which is then passed to the excel connection.

Comment: @goofyui if you are looking for a detailed step-by-step article covering this issue, check the hyperlink that i provided in my answer.

Comment: @Hadi .. thank you ..let me check that

Comment: @goofyui i added more links check out, new links contains screenshots that can help more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform this in 3 steps:

1. In the for each loop container, go to Variable Mappings and Map the result of the loop into a variable.
2. On the Excel Connection Manager, Go to expressions, Set the value of `ExcelFilePath` property expression to the variable you created in the for each loop.
3. On the dataflow task Change the `Delay Validation` property value to True.

For a detailed step-by-step tutorials, check the following links:

- [Loop through Excel Files and Tables by Using a Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/loop-through-excel-files-and-tables-by-using-a-foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How to read data from multiple Excel files with SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/)
- [Loop Through Excel Files in SSIS](https://mikedavissql.com/2013/09/16/loop-through-excel-files-in-ssis/)
- [How to loop through Excel files and load them into a database using SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package)

Comment: I am facing an error on Expression Evaluation .. Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::TestFilePath] + ";Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";

Comment: Don't assign expression to `ConnectionString` property, assign it to `ExcelFilePath property`

Comment: Or write it as following: `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @[User::TestFilePath] + ";Extended Properties=""EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES"";"`  ... you missed to start with a double quotation

Comment: Thank you.. but problem with ExcelFilePath Property is, we need to provide the actual path of the excel file. Once the package is developed in Dev environment, we will be moving to different environments to run the package from the Job Scheduler. So it is better to have it in the connection string property where we can achieve this dynamically

Comment: This is why i mentioned that you have to set the `Delay Validation` property to `True`