# ssis - how to parameterize excel connection

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-connection-manager

I need to load a .xlsx source to do some things. I've made an Excel Connection Manager and it works but I need to parameterize it to use a dynamic path. How can I do that? I've read a lot of guides but I couldn't get it to work. How do I define the path variable and how do I use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962691/how-to-set-file-source-via-parameter-in-ssis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set file source via Parameter in SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52962691/how-to-set-file-source-via-parameter-in-ssis)

Comment: yes, thanks @digital.aaron